# Why does wget -O- output to stdout?

Tags: bash, wget

Option `-O file` is used to have `wget` output to a specific `file`.

Why does `wget -O- "$url"` output to stdout? There is no such expression `-O-` in `man wget`.  Why does the second character `-` in `-O-` mean downloading the `"$url"` and outputting it to stdout?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

By posix standard, if a program takes a file path  argument for output, `-` is used to mean "standard output". The man page describes this under `-O`.

Comment: If a single-letter option `-X` takes an argument, you can use either `-X arg` or `-Xarg`. That's absolutely standard.

Comment: It's "standard" in the literal sense that it's standardized as part of the POSIX utility argument syntax guidelines -- see http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/V1_chap12.html *[A] conforming implementation shall also permit applications to specify the option and option-argument in the same argument string without intervening blank characters*, that being the "except as noted" clause referred to by utility syntax guideline 6 (near the end of the same document).

Comment: Also, see Guideline 13 by the end of that same document -- meaning it's not just a "loose convention" that `-` refers to stdin or stdout, but likewise a POSIX mandate (albeit only a mandate applicable to POSIX-standardized utilities).

Comment: I stand corrected.  So arguments with optional parameters _should_ omit the space.  Options with required parameters (such as `-O` for wget) _should_ have a space but _must_ also work without it.  Interesting, thanks for the correction.

Answer (score 3):

https://www.gnu.org/software/wget/manual/wget.html#Download-Options:

> **‘-O *file*’**
> **‘--output-document=*file*’**
>
> The documents will not be written to the appropriate files, but all will be concatenated together and written to *file*. **If ‘-’ is used as *file*, documents will be printed to standard output, disabling link conversion.** (Use ‘./-’ to print to a file literally named ‘-’.)